# Getting string value of required input (html) on cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cheerio

I'm trying to do a notify function in my website. The button his on HTML (client side) and on press calls a node js function to execute a python script that sends an e-mail to myself (tested and working).

This is my code on the client side (index.html)

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
      <form class="form-container" name="form-owner">
        <h1>Notify Owner</h1>
        <label><b>Name</b></label>
        <input id="name" style="width:90%" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
        <label><b>Message</b></label>
        <input id="context" style="width:90%" type="text" placeholder="Enter Reason" required>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="notifyOwner()">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
...
```

The code on the server side (app.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const child_process = require('child_process')
const app = express()
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const port = 80
'use strict';
var request = require('request');

...

app.post("/api/notify", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const $ = cheerio.load('<input id="name" style="width:90%" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>');
    var subject = $('[id=name]').text();
    var body = "ok";
    child_process.execSync('python3 sendEmail.py ' + subject + " " + body);
  }catch(error){
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

The varialbe 'subject' turns out as null and the script is not runned because that argument is missing

Comment: I don’t get what this involvement of Cheerio is supposed to achieve here? Who is sitting in your server room, that you expect them to fill out a form field there now?

Comment: for what i've searched cheerio can do that connection between client html and the node js server. This is a simple website for me and my -friends that controls a minecraft server everytime they want to report anything to me they can just fill the for and an email will be sent to me

Comment: (Also, I think you should look into what kind of escaping or delimiting those parameters on the shell might need, otherwise this is likely to blow up or at least give unexpected results, as soon as subject or body contain a space character … And a malicious user will probably even be able to execute arbitrary code this way.)

Comment: the ultimate goal is just to 'transfer' the values on the the inputs 'name' and 'subject' and passed them as arguments on my python function that is called on the node js server

Comment: I don’t know Cheerio, so I might be wrong here - but from what I read on the project website, I’m rather thinking you might be mistaken here. _“Cheerio parses markup and provides an API for traversing/manipulating the resulting data structure. It does not interpret the result as a web browser does. Specifically, it does not produce a visual rendering, apply CSS, load external resources, or execute JavaScript.”_ - doesn’t sound to me, as if this was supposed to interact with any data entered on the client directly?

Comment: Transferring the values you input into the fields on the client side, to the server - that’s what submitting the form already does, no? I don’t see why or how that would require any extra steps, or even libraries that port jQuery to the server side, in the first place.

Comment: well i can't do document.getElementById on node js and haven't found anything on the internet i guess that i'm just not searching for the right things.

Comment: I don't know if this makes any difference but i only do `app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('');
})`
to deploy the index.html

Comment: Your form action and method need to match /api/notify and post. The inputs will be in req.query

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's some confusion here. Cheerio is used to parse and manipulate HTML strings, but that's not what your front end code is sending. The string you're telling Cheerio to manipulate has no relationship to the request form payload in any way, nor is it a necessary tool for processing the POST request.

You appear to be using JS to submit JSON or form data to the server (as opposed to an HTML form action). `req.body` and `req.query` would contain this parsed payload respectively, depending on how your server is set up.

Here's an example of how you can set this up using JSON. Note that I've promisified the `exec` function to avoid blocking the event loop with a synchronous subprocess call.

Also, the form `name` and `context` don't seem to correspond well with `subject` and `body`--I assume you'll make this consistent.

You'll want to escape and properly quote your subprocess argument string as well.

`public/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<form>
  <h1>Notify Owner</h1>
  <label>
    <b>Name</b>
    <input id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
  </label>
  <label>
    <b>Message</b>
    <input id="context" placeholder="Enter Reason" required>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const name = event.target.querySelector("#name").value;
  const message = event.target.querySelector("#context").value;

  fetch("/api/notify", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({name, message})
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }

      return res.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      event.target.reset();
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`server.js`:

```js
const {promisify} = require("util");
const exec = promisify(require("child_process").exec);
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.post("/api/notify", async (req, res) => {
  const {name, message} = req.body; // TODO validate
  // do stuff with name and message
  console.log(name, message);

  try {
    //await exec(`python3 sendEmail.py ${subject} ${body}`);
    res.json({message: "email sent"});
  }
  catch (err) {
    res.json({error: "failed to send email"});
  }
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log("listening on port 8000"));
```